# Microsoft Translator API in Windows Phone 8.1 gives System.Net.WebException

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, system.net, microsoft-translator, system.net.httpwebrequest

I am developing an Windows Phone 8.1 app which uses the Microsoft Translator API and I am following [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/translation/p/windowsphone8.aspx) tutorial to develop the app. I have acquired an `clientID` and a `clientSecret` string and assidned it as follows.

```
String strRequestDetails = string.Format("grant_type=client_credentials&client_id={0}&client_secret={1}&scope=http://api.microsofttranslator.com", System.Net.WebUtility.UrlEncode(clientID), System.Net.WebUtility.UrlEncode(clientSecret));
```

Note: as `System.Net.HttpUtility.UrlEncode()` is not available Windows Phone 8.1, I had to resort to `System.Net.WebUtility.UrlEncode(clientSecret)`.

However I get an unhandled exception called

> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (400)
>   Bad Request.

at this point `HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.EndGetResponse(ar);`

I appreciate if anyone can tell me how to solve this issue? Thank you.